# Run proprietary [java] application with a custom graphical layer

Tags: java, c++, windows, graphics, desktop-application

We have a proprietary application in our office, running on Windows, missing some features providing custom Data Overlay. We just want to highlight some data in a dialog.

Since there is no plugin-mechanism we can use, I am thinking of running the application with a separate graphical layer on top of it which is typically transparent, but when the dialog is open, I want to modify the layer to highlight the special data.

Since it is a Java application, this may could be done by decompiling, but what if it's a signed jar? Anyway I am more interested in a solution, that is not specific to Java.

Sorry for only giving an overview, feel free to ask for clarification/further information!

[EDIT]

We did it the "slow" way. Ask the producer to modify it and wait for month.

Anyway I'm still interesting in solutions

Comment: Do you know where the data is stored...?

Comment: not now (starting tomorrow...). Anyway modifying data would only bring benefits, if the logic of marking data is stored in the DB. I can't just treat my valueable data as "other valuable data" which is already highlighted, because that would break calculations made on them...

Answer (score 0):

IMHO signed jar is not big deal unless this proprietary validates this signature inside. But even in this case, since you will have source you can delete such validation.

Another approach would be to use your own ClassLoader, intercept classes what you want to change and substitute them with your own classes. For example you substitute JTextField with your own myJTextField which  highlights the special data.